# Character mismatching in C Program

Tags: c

I'm trying to check whether the value entered for password_entered contains a digit anywhere in it.

However, I'm running into a few errors:

1. The compiler is complaining im passing a `int` here, when I'm really trying to pass a `char`:

   scanf("%s", password_entered);
2. And this line is complaining that I'm using conflicting types:

   char CD(char password_entered)

(for some reason this code will not properly look like code - any help, greatly appreciated).

```
int main()
{

    char password_entered[20]; //max is 20 char

    char CD(char password_entered[]);

    printf("Please enter a password");
    scanf("%s", password_entered);

    if (CD(password_entered)){
        printf("You entered a password with a digit!");
    }

    return 0;
}

char CD(char password_entered) {
    for(i=0; i<=strlen(password_entered); i++){
        if(isdigit(password_entered)){
            //contains a digit
            return '1';
        }
        else{
            return 0;
        }
    }

}
```

**UPDATED CODE:**
I'm still getting an error on: char `CD(char password_entered) {` of "error: expected ';', ',' , or ')' .

What am i doing wrong here?

Thank you.

Comment: Max is 20 char? No it ain't! Max is 1 char. You need an array.

Comment: Can you please reply with some code, i'd appreciate it.

Comment: Why do you pass string as argument when its parameter type of function is char ?

Comment: Where is isdigit(password_entered) ?

Comment: password_entered is entered in do{}

Comment: Did you `#include <stdio.h>`? If you did, edit your question to show that in your code.... Also for `<ctype.h>`

Comment: Don't put function declarations inside your `main` - or inside any other function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, declare password_entered as char array:

```
char password_entered[20];
```

You are passing a string to the CD:

> while( CD(password_entered) != 1 );

and grabbing values in char:

> char CD(char password_entered)

`password_entered` is a char array, not a char.
It should be `char CD(char[] password_entered)`

And your last function:

```
if(isdigit(password_entered))
{

//contains a digit

 return '1';

 }

 else{

  return '1';

  }
```

should be

```
if(isdigit(password_entered[i])){
            //contains a digit
            return '1';
        }
        else{
            return '1';
        }
```

This is how your code should look like:

```
int main()
{    
    //int password_min=6;

    char password_entered[20]; //max is 20 char

    //functions
    bool CD(char password_entered);
    // It should be declared above


    // do{
    //     printf("Please enter a password");
    //     scanf("%s", password_entered); // you are reading in an array, which is not correct
    // }
    // while( CD(password_entered) != 1 );

    printf("Please enter a password");
    scanf("%s", password_entered);

    if ( CD(password_entered))
    {
        // a password
    }


    return 0;
}

// Check for digits in password_entered var
char CD(char[] password_entered) {
    int flag = 0;
    for(i=0; i<=strlen(password_entered); i++){
        if(isdigit(password_entered)){
            //contains a digit
            return '1';
        }
        else{
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if ( flag )
        return -1;
    else
        return 1;
}
```

Edit final : This is the way your program should be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{

    char password_entered[20]; //max is 20 char

    //functions
    char CD(char password_entered[]);


    //do{}
    printf("Please enter a password");
    scanf("%s", password_entered);
    //}
    //while( CD(password_entered) != 1 );

    if (CD(password_entered)){
        printf("You entered a password with a digit!");
    }

    return 0;
}

// Check for digits in password_entered var
char CD(char password_entered[]) {
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<=strlen(password_entered); i++){
        if(isdigit(password_entered)){
            //contains a digit
            return '1';
        }
        else{
            return 0;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I incoporated a lot of your code, but this line: "char CD(char[] password_entered) {"   is throwing an error of "expected ';', ',' , or ')' . Any idea?

Comment: Also, line: bool checkForDigits(char password_entered);  is throwing "expected char but argument is a type 'char *'

Comment: ok.. but I can't understand : for some reason this code will not properly look like code, why is it so? Is it your full code?

Comment: See my edit. If you want full code, do post your fulll code. Looks like you are not revealing all of your code. :D

Comment: @learner  You can't pass a complete array inside `isdigit` function. As you take input in `password_entered` what if someone entered password of length `20 characters` it will show undefined behaviour.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Function prototype is of type `bool`-`bool CD(char password_entered);`

and you define it with type `char`- `char CD(char password_entered)`

That's why you get error. Keep one type for the function `CD`(According to me you should use `char CD()`).

Other problems-

```
char password_entered; //max is 20 char
```

Declaread as `char`. In this`scanf("%s", password_entered);` the specifier `%s` expects a `char *` and you pass a `char`.

```
  for(i=0; i<=strlen(password_entered); i++){
```

Function `strlen` is used to calculate the length of string. You can't use it for a character.

You need to declare `password_entered` as an array with appropriate size. Something like this -

```
char password_entered[20];
scanf("%19s", password_entered);  //so that 1 place remains for null character else code will give UB
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define PASS_SIZE 20

char pass[PASS_SIZE + 1];   /* 1 for \0 */  
bool is_ok(char*);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

  int t = 0;
  do{

      printf("Enter password : ");
      gets(pass);                   /* try to use fgets */      
                                    /* for bound checking */
  }while(!is_ok(pass));

  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);   /* done */

} // int main

bool is_ok(char *pass){

   for(register int i = 0; i < strlen(pass); i++)
       if(!isdigit(pass[i]))
            return false;

   return true;

} // check that all are digits
```

Comment: To answer the question, it isn't required to got through the whole reading procedure,